# 2 GCM registrationId for same android application

Tags: android, sdk, google-cloud-messaging

I have 2 GCM BroadcastReceivers in my application (One for an android library integrated in my application and one for my own application).
Both of them are registered in the manifest and have the same category (Which is my application package name).

Both have registration with register() function and both receives different valid registrationId's (because the senderId for both are different).

My problem is that I have everything work fine (Both Recievers get the push notification) but after a couple of hours when trying to send a push from Server I encounter "NotRegistered" issue in my server (android library regId) and registrationId seems invalid all of a sudden.

So my question is can I have 2 different GCM "Mechanism" in the same application with different senderId without a collision or some sort on GCM Servers ?

Comment: Are you using the library which help you to implement GCM mechanism? If yes then how that library is having its own senderID, it should give you option to keep your senderID. Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using an SDK I built. It has it own senderId (Taken the package name of the SDK from Google Console API). It doesn't help me implement GCM, it is implement GCM on its own and another application which uses it implement GCM on its own with their senderId (with their own package name). Obviously both have different registrationId because of that.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, It will never create collision as both will work as different applications (Both is having different SENDER_ID).

Check the following notes :

1) Make sure that you have added different category name (With INTENT-FILTER) for both library and application :

```
<receiver
    android:name=".xxxxx"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.xxxx" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2) Sometimes the Reg Id is getting changed automatically so try to save the previous one and check each time if it is same, if not then you have to update new one with your server.

UPDATE :

When you send a message, you specify a registration ID, which is implicitly linked to the package name of the app and device where it was generated. Only the app which requested the registration ID will receive your message. So it will conflict because you are using the same library (Same Package name) with different applications.

So your solution might be to do all stuff related to GCM in SingleToneClass with library. In which you will pass your application package name to register with GCM. So whenever you will use your library with different applications, It will refer different package name and SENDER_ID will be the same but it will not cause problem as package name will be changed.

Comment: That's exactly what I had. It did not work after a while, getting same issue. Also, if I will have the one more application using this SDK on my device, wouldn't it create a problem then ? Same senderId and same device for in a SDK for 2 different applications ?

Comment: OK, so that's why I have recieved "NotRegistered" error from GCM trying to send a push? I can't use the same senderId for my SDK for multiple applications that integrate my SDK ? So another question please, if I'll have the same senderId as my embracing application, will it work well ? (Meaning have 2 broadcast recivers with same category (one for library, one for embracing application with same senderId and get same regId) ? I don't want who ever integrate my SDK to handle my pushes. On the other hand with their senderId everything should be duplicate, will it cause any problem ?